# Debugger gets stuck in WPF OnStartup method

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-debugging

I am experiencing a problem in my project where if I get an exception in OnStartup code in App.xaml.cs debugger will breakpoint first and when I click continue it will run and breakpoint at the same location rather than exiting app.

However if I add DispatcherUnhandledException event handler in App.xaml.cs and **empty** event handler it will work as expected.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication8.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources />
</Application>
```

App.Xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var b = 4 - 4;
        var a = 100/b;
    }

    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {

    } 
}
```

To reproduce issue remove event handler from code behind.

Solution details: WPF, .Net 4 (with all current updates), Visual Studio 20013 update 3.

Could anyone explain why do I get this behaviour?

Comment: You are trying to call the base class's OnStartup function after you have override it?

Comment: @user2378527 Yes I am, as you can see from the code. I don't really understand the question here..